# Use a while loop to print words from the list until a word of length 4 would be printed

Tags: python

I am trying to use a while loop to print out words from a list that is in a text file. I need the loop to stop once it reaches a word that is 4 characters long. With my current code I am getting an infinite loop.

```
wordsFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
wordsFile.close()
wordList = words.split()

# While loop displays names based on length of words in list

print("\nSelected words are:")
while words in wordList:
if len(words) != 4:
    print(words)
```

**Sample Desired Output**

Selected words are:

- Abate
- Chicanery
- disseminate
- gainsay
- latent
- aberrant
- coagulate
- dissolution
- garrulous

Comment: When posting questions, you should try to isolate the problem in your code as much as possible from irrelevant details. In this case, the source of the list of words is irrelevant to the action of printing words from a list based on length.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `break` if your word length is equal to 4. Also, it isn't `while words in wordList:`, it is `for words in wordList:`. Using `While expression` statement, it will iterate until that expression `become` `False`, but `words in wordList` will be always `True`. So you will get a infinite loop.

```
if len(words)==4:
    break
```

You will get the following:

```
for word in wordList:
    if len(word)==4:
        break
    print(words)
```

What is a `break` statement do ? It stops your loop a execute the next line after your loop. It works as well in `for` loops

Comment: Hi levi, I tried out your code and it seems to still give me an infinite loop. Even with the break in the loop. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @tronicx You should use for instead of while. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Much of your code is close but off, and it seems like you don't quite understand how loops and conditionals work.

Try the following:

```
for word in words:
    # will not print the first word of length 4 which breaks the loop
    if len(word) == 4:
        break
    print(word)
```

Comment: if i read the question correctly, the if condition should be `== 4` and should be after the print.

Comment: On second reading, I think you're right about the length condition. Judging from the sample desired output, it looks like the first word of length 4 to break it shouldn't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert all the words from a text file into a LIST of strings and then read through the string and print all the words that have more or less than four letters? If so you are going to need to loop through the file and append each word to a list of words.

If not, I suggest using continue instead of break

```
for word in wordList:
    if len(word) == 4:
        continue
    else:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

recall = 0

for word in wordList:

```
while recall == 0:
    if len(word) != 4:
        print(word)
        break
    else:
        recall = 1
```

Say HI to Leon Tietz from Mars (out of this world) Y'all IT 210 kiddos!